# Как вызвать функцию в другой AJAX функции?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Есть функция, которая должна менять стоимость доставки определенного метода. Она работает, и меняет цену. Но это работает только при загрузки страницы один раз, а в моем магазине, в корзине можно менять город доставки. Так вот, нужно сделать так, чтобы эта функция работала при каждом изменении поля города без перезагрузки страницы. Я попытался засунуть эту функцию в ajax функцию, но ничего не получилось. Может не правильно вызываю? Вообщем нужна помощь, или другое решение как это можно реализовать

**change_flat_rates_cost функция (меняет цену доставки, в зависимости от города)**

```
function change_flat_rates_cost($rates, $package) { 

$userid = get_current_user_id();

$meta_city = get_user_meta( $userid, 'billing_city', true );

if ( isset( $rates['shipping_method_1'] ) ) {
if ($meta_city == 'City1'){
    $rates['shipping_method_1']->cost = 100;
}

if ($meta_city == 'City2'){
    $rates['shipping_method_1']->cost = 200;
}

}
return $rates;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'change_flat_rates_cost', 10, 2 );
```

**ajax функция (сама функция вызывается, но то что внутри - не работает):**

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_change_shipping', 'change_shipping' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_change_shipping', 'change_shipping' );

function change_shipping() { 
global $woocommerce;

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'change_flat_rates_cost', 10, 2 );

die();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**ЧАСТЬ 1.** Почему не работает.

Функция `change_shipping()` ничего не делает, только устанавливает хук, т.е. записывает в таблицу хуков WordPress некую информацию, после чего умирает. Вызова функции `change_flat_rates_cost()` не происходит - некому ее вызывать.

**ЧАСТЬ 2.** Что делать.

К сожалению, без перезагрузки страницы ничего не выйдет. Из вопроса не вполне понятно, о какой странице идет речь, но, по всей видимости, это checkout. Надо программно "нажать" кнопку "Обновить корзину". Как это сделать, я описал в этом ответе: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/629701/220220

Comment: А каким либо другим образом вызвать функцию можно в моей ajax функции?

У меня и корзина и checkout на одной странице (прилепил корзину к чекауту сверху). По поводу кнопки обновить корзину, это отчасти решает проблему, но появляются подводные камни. 
Во первых: У кнопки "обновить корзину" стоит аттрибут disabled, и по ней нельзя кликнуть, только если изменить количество товара, она становится активной.
Во вторых: Если ручками убрать этот атрибут в исходном коде, то при нажатии на кнопку обновить корзину - у меня обновляются и все поля (имя, адрес и т.д). Эти поля становятся опять пустыми

Comment: аттрибут disabled убрал, с помощью jquery, но то что при обновлении корзины чистятся все поля чекаута на этой страницы - это плохо. как можно это обойти?

Comment: Это более чем странно. Видимо, неправильно настроен или доработан WooCommerce. При обновлении checkout поля не чистятся. Можете посмотреть на тестовом сайте http://test.kagg.eu/checkout/

Comment: у вас checkout находится на отдельной странице от корзины, поэтому и логически понятно что поля чекаут не будут очищатся. на том тестовом сайте на странице чекаут нет даже этой кнопки обновить корзину. у меня на одной и корзина и чекаут, видимо сама кнопка предназначена чтобы обновлять информацию на всей странице без перезагрузки, иначе никак не объяснить почему поля "заново" грузятся аяксом. $( 'body' ).trigger( 'update_checkout' ) вот типо такого что то нужно, этот тригер не обновляет поля. но именно он не подходит, из за того что тригер не запускает php скрипт заново

Comment: Покажите ваш сайт

Comment: тут они не очищаются даже, а аяксом заново подгружаются, потому что если зарегистрированным зайти, то там поля подгружают сохраненную инфу. так вот, в тех полях где есть сохраненная инфа, там остается текст после обновления (сохраненный с базы данных). а в полях где текста не было, то они будут пустыми при обновлении корзины. такое ощущение что просто какая то аякс функция загружает заново кусок страницы и заменяет старый код. вот только как это исправить

Comment: Да у вас там и без аякса какой-то скрипт чистит поля. Я попробовал ввести имя и перейти на следующее поле - и все, имя пропало. Там не в вукомерс дело, и не в том, что корзина и чекаут на одной странице. Вот вам пример сайта, где корзина вместе с чекаутом и все ок: igrolog-school.ru

Comment: это из за кнопки обновить корзину, и скрипта, который программно жмет кнопку при изменении количества товара. почему то он жмет кнопку при изменении любого поля. временно скрипт убрал, посмотрите сейчас (только кеш обновите)

Comment: Стало лучше, но обновление страницы все равно чистит поля. Так быть не должно. На сайте, что я показал, такого нет. К вопросу и моему ответу эта ошибка у вас на сайте отношения не имеет.

Comment: на том сайте вы делали? возможно я не правильно объединил страницу cart и checkout? я скопировал весь код из cart.php и вставил в начало файла form-checkout.php. или каким лучше способом объединять, чтобы такого не было? поля не чистятся, а подгружаются заново аяксом. у зарегистрированного юзера поле почты не чистится, а загружается заново как было

Comment: Все, связанное с WooCommerce, на том сайте делал я. Корзина на чекауте реализована плагином. Завтра скажу, каким. Так, как вы сделали - это очень жесткое насилие над WC, система очень сложная и такого не прощает ))

Comment: все таки да, то что я уже перелопатил весь этот вукомерс, дает о себе знать. я ведь тоже все что на этом сайте сам сделал, и голова от кода выдает такие вот вещи. не правильно я объединил страницы. нашел плагин, возможно тот о котором вы хотели сказать. он мне объединил страницы и все работает как нужно. тут и проблемка решилась основная, повесил скрипт на кнопку - цена обновляется без перезагрузки страницы и поля не чистятся. вообщем спасибо за наводку, а то голова уже кипит

Comment: На том сайте, что я показывал, я использовал плагин WooCommerce Menu Cart: https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-menu-bar-cart/