# Обновление цены и методов доставки на странице оформления заказа

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

У меня вопрос по WooCommerce. На странице оформления заказа у меня есть кастомное поле time, при изменении которого должна обновляться цена, а главное, методы доставки. Вот эта страница http://oliva.acesspades.com/cart/.
При изменении времени должна меняться цена доставки. В самом методе доставки условие прописано и оно работает.
То, что я перепробовал:

1. Поставить самому полю класс 'shipping_method'
2. Поставить полю класс 'update_totals_on_change'
3. https://techglimpse.com/update-order-review-on-state-change/

Везде один эффект, вроде обновляется, но по факту данные не обновляются.

Уже весь интернет перерыл, может чем поможете)

Comment: какое условие должно быть? Что должно быть при изменение поля time ?

Comment: [ссылка](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45806249/change-product-variation-prices-via-a-hook-in-woocommerce-3)

Comment: [Ссылка](https://www.skyverge.com/blog/change-woocommerce-price-display/)

Comment: [ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/629673/woocommerce-%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B7%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC/629701)

Answer (score 1):

В итоге сделал костыль, который принудительно меняет город на другой и обратно. Да, не очень, но всё-таки работает

```
$('#time').change(function(){
    if($('#billing_country').val()==446){// Если город Москва
        $('#billing_country').val('513');// Меняем город
        $('#billing_country').trigger('change');// Запускаем обновление 
        $( 'body' ).on( 'updated_checkout', function() {// Когда обновление завершается
            if($('#billing_country').val()!=446){
                $('#billing_country').val('446');// Выбираем обратно Москву
                $('#billing_country').trigger('change');// И запускаем обновление
            } 
        });
    }

});
```